# ActiveMQ CMS: All Message Properties Show as String Type

Tags: activemq-classic

I'm a new user of ActiveMQ CMS (ActiveMQ-cpp-3.9.3), and new to JMS as well.  I am creating, populating, and sending test messages to myself to start.  In my code to consume those messages, I check the property type of all the message properties.

I noticed that the property type of all the properties in my test message is being reported as `STRING_TYPE` by `getPropertyValueType()`.  This includes several pre-defined properties that I would not think would be strings, such as the "persistent" flag (I would've thought it was a boolean), "priority" (I would think integer), "timestamp" (I would think long?).  I also created a user-defined integer property, which is also assessed to be a string.

Am I misunderstanding something about how the property types work?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I've done a little more research, and discovered why this is happening.

It turns out that this behavior is a known quirk in the way that ActiveMQ-cpp handles message properties when the stomp transport is employed (as it is in my case).  All message properties are transmitted as string types when stomp transport is used.  See [this description on the ActiveMQ-cpp Web site](http://activemq.apache.org/cms/stomp-support.html) for more info.